# perl - send multiple request in database

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, mariadb

i have this script in  perl, this program parse a log file and send result in a database, my ploblem is my script insert only one request, i need insert multiple request :

```
#Connect to the database.
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=database;host=IP",
"hostname", 'password',
{'RaiseError' => 1});



while (my ($user, $ref) = each %counts) {
  while (my ($program, $count) = each %$ref) {
    #print "$count OSUSER with session $user and with program $program\n";
    print "time = $time, count = $count, user = $user, program = $program, last_line = $last_line\n";

    $request ="'$time', '$count', '$user', '$program', $last_line";

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("REPLACE `test` (time, nb, os_name, program, last_line) VALUES($request);")
    or die "prepare statement failed: $dbh->errstr()";

    $sth->execute() or die "execution failed: $dbh->errstr()";
    print $sth->rows . " rows found.\n";
    $sth->finish;
  }
}
```

my log:

```
       ID USER                    TERMINAL        SERVICE                    
---------- ------------------------- --------------- -------------------------  
         1 toto                    titi     roro          
         2 toto                    titi     roro          
         4 gigi                    gege        fefe
```

my database:

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| ID | time                | nb        | os_name     | program        | last_line |
+----+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| 15  | 2019-01-04 14:00:00|        33 | titi        | roro           | 109       |
```

i want :

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| ID | time                | nb        | os_name     | program        | last_line |
+----+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| 15  | 2019-01-04 14:00:00|        33 | titi        | roro           | 109       |
| 16  | 2019-01-04 14:00:00|        9  | gege        | fefe           | 109       |
```

(Added by Dave Cross - copied from a comment. Here is the table definition.)

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time datetime NOT NULL,
  nb int NOT NULL,
  os_name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
  program nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
  last_line nvarchar(100)NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY (time)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Why are you using `REPLACE` without a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Also, why don't you prepare before the loop and use placeholders in execute?

Comment: with replace i can add more request

Comment: What is the primary key of `test`?

Comment: Use **placeholder values**. You can't just jam in a raw string into your query.

Comment: Why did you define `time` unique, if you want to have the same time twice? Also, you should use @<username> like @jack94 in a comment, if you want that the user you reply to gets a notification about your reply and thus can reply too. And you should edit your question for adding code, like `CREATE` statements, it's not formatted in comments and hard to read.

Comment: @choroba  i create table like that : CREATE TABLE test ( ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , time datetime NOT NULL, nb int NOT NULL, os_name nvarchar(100)NOT NULL, program nvarchar(100)NOT NULL, last_line nvarchar(100)NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID), UNIQUE KEY (time) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: @tadman , i use placeholder

Comment: Also: What does the script print to the console when you run it?

Comment: @jack94: You don't use placeholders in the code you've shown us.

Comment: the script print 2 rows found. and in database only one request is added :
 +----+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| ID | time                | nb        | os_name     | program        | last_line |
+----+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| 15  | 2019-01-04 14:00:00|        33 | titi        | roro           | 109       |

Comment: `VALUES($request)` says you're not using placeholders. I can see on an earlier line you have the data just slapped in **without escaping** which is a [huge problem](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Your table definition (from a comment) includes this:

```
UNIQUE KEY (time)
```

So your table can only ever include a single row for any value of `time`.

Also, you use `REPLACE` in your SQL. So when you run your statement for a second time, your database sees there is an existing row with the same unique key, so it updates the row rather than inserting a new one.

Seems to me that your code is working exactly as expected. If you want to add more rows, you need to change the value in `$time`.

**Update:**

From your comment on another answer.

> i tested with INSERT but don't work : DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '2019-01-04 17:45:00' for key 'time'

Yes! That's exactly what should happen. By declaring you `time` column as `UNIQUE` you are telling your database that each time value can only occur once in your table. So if you try to insert another row with the same time (which is what you are doing) you get that error.

So you switch from `INSERT` to `REPLACE` and you get no error, but only one row inserted - because that is what `REPLACE` does.

The example you give of what you want in the table has two identical values in the time column. That cannot happen while you have the `UNIQUE` definition on that column. That is exactly what the `UNIQUE` key is there to prevent.

You need to step back and think about exactly what you want in the table. If you want duplicate time values in the table then you need to remove the `UNIQUE` key definition on the table (and then change `REPLACE` with `INSERT`).

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual for `REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html):

> `REPLACE` works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` **or a `UNIQUE` index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted**.

(Emphasis: Me)

There you have it. You have the same time `2019-01-04 14:00:00` twice. When `REPLACE`ing the second one the first one gets deleted

Try to remove the unique index on `time`.

Comment: i tested with INSERT but don't work : DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '2019-01-04 17:45:00' for key 'time' at test2.pl line 83, <$IN> line 181.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Duplicate entry '2019-01-04 17:45:00' for key 'time' at test2.pl line 83, <$IN> line 181.

Comment: @jack94 Do you understand what the `unique key (time)` does? If you want more rows, you need them to have different timestamps. Alternatively, remove the `unique key(time)` constraint from the table.